# Display mean of all numbers written by user MATLAB

Tags: loops, mean

I am quite new to matlab and I have to write a program where you can enter a number of values in the command window, and the program should continue to ask the user to enter a number until the user enters the number 0. When entering 0 the program should display the mean value, the largest number entered and the smallest number entered. I have gotten to the point where I can enter values. However, the program only displays the most recent entered value when showing max, min and mean value in the x.

Would be very thankful for advice on how to proceed.

This is the code I have now:

```
   function laboration_20150431
   Loop = true;
   while(Loop)

    s = input('Write number, enter 0 to quit:');
        if s~=0
           Loop = true;

       else 

           Loop = false;
        end
    end


    meanvalue = mean(s);
    highest = max(s);
    lowest = min(s);


    disp(['Mean value: ' num2str(meanvalue)]);
    disp(['Max value: ' num2str(highest)]);
    disp(['Min value: ' num2str(lowest)]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable s is always overwritten. You should use an additional array. Something like this:

```
function laboration_20150431
   Loop = true;
   x=[];
   while(Loop)

    s = input('Write number, enter 0 to quit:');
        if s~=0
           Loop = true;
           x = [x s]; 
       else 

           Loop = false;
        end
    end


    meanvalue = mean(x);
    highest = max(x);
    lowest = min(x);


    disp(['Mean value: ' num2str(meanvalue)]);
    disp(['Max value: ' num2str(highest)]);
    disp(['Min value: ' num2str(lowest)]);
```

The new input 's' is appended to the end of 'x' if it's not zero.